# error when using networkx to drow a precision matrix of financial network

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, networkx, financial

I want to draw the precision matrix (inverse covariance) of a financial networks including 200 stocks. It popped up an error

> 'AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'ishold''.

plus:how can I draw pic like that the size of vertex is proportionate to its variance, the width of the edges is proportionate to its correlation.

```
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(prec_filtered, 'var1', 'var2')

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='orange', node_size=400, edge_color='black', linewidths=1, font_size=1)
```

Comment: Writing urgent in caps with that many exclamation marks might not do what you hope. Writing a clear question explaining what you've done so far usually takes you a lot longer.